# Can a Google Voice number be daisy chained to another Google Voice number?

Tags: google-voice

Can a Google Voice number be daisy chained to another Google Voice number?

In other words, can you add a Google Voice number to another Google Voice account? Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

I just tried it.

```
Cannot add another Google Voice phone number as a forwarding number.
```

So, the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google doesn't allow you to do this, I think your only option is to use another carrier in between the two. For example, if you had a Skype account which can receive phone calls at a number (i.e. Skype In), and was able to forward those calls to a cell phone, you should probably be able to do the following:

- Google Voice Account A -> Skype Account -> Google Voice Account B.